# Spring-data-mongo: MongoRepository not being wired unless I add @Component annotation

Tags: spring, jakarta-ee, autowired, spring-data-mongodb

I am having a little weird behavior with my `spring-data-mongo` where my repository package is not being scanned by the `<mongo:repositories/>` tag. I am using spring 3.2.3.RELEASE with spring-data-mongo 1.2.1.RELEASE.

I have a project called `edowmis` and in it there are `2 maven modules`, `datalayer` and `web` which a webapp.I am using the `datalayer` in isolation so the other module can be ignored. I have an application context for datalayer 
[image: datalayer config]

So I wanted to test my setup by writing a small Unit/Integration test but I've noticed I can't autowire my `UserRepository` because It says there isn't such a bean
[image: unit test]

Since I am using IntelliJ I can see certain visuals when things are ok and not ok. I've addec `<context:component-scan/>` to my application context but no result.
[image: UserRepository not bein scanned]

But when I add the `@Component` annotation it has started identifying the Class.
[image: Component being scanned]

all information you might need is on [pastie.org](http://pastie.org/8148930)

Is the `@component` or `@Repository` really necessary or something is wrong with my configuration?

Comment: Hi, did you find a solution for this problem?

Comment: No bruv! I did add the annotation to them in order to get them work. sorry

Comment: same problem here. Seems that intellij doesn't recognize the EnableMongoRepositories annotation/config

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the @Component or @Repository is necessary.  The scan simply indicates that spring should look for classes identified via annotations (@Component, @Repository, @Service) and load them as beans.  If you don't use repository or component scan, you would have to manually instantiate all spring-managed beans via XML configuration or Java configuration.

You have to tell spring which classes to turn into beans as it doesn't assume everything in the classpath is supposed to be a spring-managed bean, which is why you need to use the annotations.